# while mysqli_fetch_assoc to work while theres columns instead of rows

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry i didn't know how to make sense of this in the title.

Basically i have a table with two row in.

[image]

now i want to show the reference and then all the doc columns on my page.

However you can see i have the same reference on two rows. if the user uploads documents with the same ref i want to be able to show all the docs, under the reference.

For example i want to look like this on page:

```
11111111
word.jpg
a17.gif
Matthew Smart CV.docx
word.jpg
a17.png
Matthew Smart CV.docx
```

This is what i have done so far and got stuck

PHP/MYSQL:

```
    <?php

    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM customers ";
    $query .= "WHERE reference = 11111111";
    $results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $cnt = 0;
    $customer_doc = array();
    while($customer_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $customer_ref = $customer_details["reference"];
        $cnt ++;
        $customer_doc[] = $customer_details['doc' . $cnt];
    }
    echo $customer_ref;


    ?>
    <pre>
        <?php
        print_r($customer_doc);
        ?>
    </pre>
```

I dont know how to do this.

Can anyone be kind enough to help me so i can learn from it?

Comment: Any chance you could show me an example, if if you didn't give me the code just break it down in steps for me? It would really help me learn as i don't know where else to learn this.

Comment: Attn closevoters: Too broad? Seriously? There's a simple code solution to this, and the OP has posted a solid effort.

Comment: @matthewsmart Your sample output looks like you'd prefer them listed one value per line, beneath the `reference` value as a header? Is that correct?

Comment: yeah, ultimately they will be links to the documents. so if i search for customer by reference, they might have uploaded with same ref twice or three times.

So i want to display the customer ref at the top and then display doc 1 to 3 and then doc 1 to 3 on the row below. each on a separate line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you would eventually be querying for more than one `reference` value in a result set, the technique CBroe is mentioning in the main comment thread involves storing the last value for `reference` on each iteration of the `while` loop. If the value has changed from the previous one, you print the output. If it is the same, you do not need to print it in that loop and can instead just print the other columns.

#### Option 1 compare variable to last iteration's value:

Note: I'm doing this with extremely raw output here, just bare `echo` with a linebreak.

```
// Start with an empty value for the "last one"
$last = null;
while ($customer_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
  // Check if the newly fetched row differs from the previous value
  if ($customer_details['reference'] != $last) {
    // It is different! Print it out
    echo $customer_details['reference']  . "\n";
  }
  // Store this current one into the $last var for 
  // comparison on the next round
  $last = $customer_details['reference'];

  // Print the other columns...
  echo $customer_details['doc1'] . "\n";
  echo $customer_details['doc2'] . "\n";
  echo $customer_details['doc3'] . "\n";
}
```

#### Option 2 - indexed array storage (probably the best option, certainly the one I would use)

Now, suppose you want to store these into an array. This would be handy because you can make an array indexed by the `reference` column, with sub-arrays for the other columns. This is easier and you don't need to check if the value changes. You need only to append a sub-array on every `while` iteration.

```
// Array to hold all results:
$all = array();
while ($customer_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
  // Append a new sub-array of the 3 other cols to
  // the main array's key by reference using the []
  // array append syntax
  $all[$customer_details['reference']][] = array(
    'doc1' => $customer_details['doc1'],
    'doc2' => $customer_details['doc2'],
    'doc3' => $customer_details['doc3']
  );
}
```

The array now looks like

```
Array (
  '1111111' => Array (
     Array (
       'doc1' => 'word.jpg'
       'doc2' => 'a17.gif',
       'doc3' => 'Matthew Smart CV.docx'
     ),
     Array (
       'doc1' => 'word.jpg'
       'doc2' => 'a17.gif',
       'doc3' => 'Matthew Smart CV.docx'
     )
  ),
  '222222' => Array (
     Array (
       'doc1' => 'xyz.jpg'
       'doc2' => 'z17.gif',
       'doc3' => 'Matthew Smart CV.pdf'
     ),
     Array (
       'doc1' => 'xyz.jpg'
       'doc2' => 'z17.gif',
       'doc3' => 'Matthew Smart CV.pdf'
     ),
)
```

And so you can loop over it with a nested `foreach`. The outer gets the `reference` and the inner gets the other values:

```
foreach ($all as $reference => $rows) {
  // Write out the reference, which was the array key
  echo $reference . "\n";
  // Then in a loop, write out the others
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['doc1'] . "\n";
    echo $row['doc2'] . "\n";
    echo $row['doc3'] . "\n";
  }
}
```

#### Option 3 - query hack:

This last one is a `GROUP BY` hack you can use on your query. I don't exactly recommend it, but want to show it is possible. If you use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) together with a normal `CONCAT_WS()`, you can produce in *one* row, the `reference`, followed by all the other documents separated by something like `||`. In PHP then, you just need one loop and to `explode()` on the delimiter `||`.

```
$query = "SELECT reference, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('||', doc1, doc2, doc3) SEPARATOR '||') AS docs FROM customers GROUP BY reference";
```

This would produce rows literally structured like:

```
1111111, word.jpg||a17.gif||Matthew Smart CV.docx||word.jpg||a17.gif||Matthew Smart CV.docx
```

That is, the `reference` in a column, then all other strings joined by `||` as a column called `docs`.

```
// Execute the query, then fetch.
while ($customer_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
  echo $customer_details['reference'] . "\n";

  // Then explode() the || delimited string with linebreaks
  echo implode("\n", explode("||", $customer_details['docs']));
}
```

Again, I don't recommend actually using this, but it can be done this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i wish there was more people like you to help with questions. I'm still learning php/mysql and have been given a task at work for a customer upload portal. working in it support I'm looking to move into development and they have handed me this task to see if i can do it.

Every one has to start somewhere right? :)

But thanks again for going really in depth for what i need. As i can now learn from this code and understand more

Comment: @matthewsmart Good luck to you. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You need "group by reference" in array:

```
$customer_docs = [];
while($customer_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) 
    $customer_doc[$customer_details["reference"]][] = $customer_details;


foreach($customer_docs as $reference=>$docs){
    echo $reference;

    foreach($docs as $doc){
        echo $doc['doc1'];
        //...
    }  
    // "breakline"     
}
```

Or "classic way": add temp variable for current reference before while-loop, and every iteration compare previous reference with current.